# RBPDF fabric.js to pdf : not correct result when rotate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, pdf, fabricjs

I am converting json data to pdf using RBPDF.
Here `params[:image]` is json data produced in client side by fabricjs(`JSON.stringify()`).

```
objects = JSON.parse(params[:image])
objectid = 0 
defaultasX = 1.0
defaultasY = 1.0

@pdf = RBPDF.new()
@pdf.SetLeftMargin(10)
@pdf.SetRightMargin(10)
@pdf.set_header_margin(10)
@pdf.set_footer_margin(10)
@pdf.setPrintFooter(false)
@pdf.add_page()
 objects["state"]["objects"].map { |object|
  objectid = objectid + 1 ;
   @pdf.StartTransform()
  #fit to Screen
   if(defaultasX == 1 && defaultasX == 1)
      defaultasX = 200.0 / (object["width"] * object["scaleX"])
      defaultasY = 130.0 / (object["height"] * object["scaleY"])
   end
   left = (object["left"]) * defaultasX
   top = (object["top"]) * defaultasY
   width = object["width"] * object["scaleX"] * defaultasX
   height = object["height"] * object["scaleY"] * defaultasY

   if object["type"] == 'i-text'
     @pdf.set_xy(left,top)
     @pdf.SetFontSize(5)
     @pdf.MultiCell(width, height, object["text"])
     puts "printing text at (" + left.to_s+ ' ' + top.to_s + ' ' + width.to_s+ ' ' + height.to_s + ')'
   elsif object["type"] == 'image'
     @pdf.set_xy(left, top)
     @pdf.Rotate(360 - object["angle"])

     dataURI = object["src"]
     extension = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0].split('/')[1]
     byteString = dataURI.split(',')[1]
     filename = "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/tmpimg"+ objectid.to_s() + "." + extension
     imagefiletmp  = Base64.decode64(byteString)

       File.open(filename, 'wb') do |f|
         f.write(imagefiletmp)
       end
     @pdf.Image(filename , left, top, width, height)
     @pdf.Rect( left-5, top-5, 10, 10)
  end
  @pdf.StopTransform()
 }
 @pdf.output('./public/uploads/abc.pdf','F')
```

All things making correct result but when rotating width become long.

This is client side image part
[image]

This is pdf image part

[image]

Why this was happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabricjs transform pipeline is different.
You cannot set x,y and then rotate an object. With scale things gets even more complicated.

To make it easier i would suggest you to:
in fabricJs work with originX and originY set to 'center'

```
fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';
```

Then when is pdf time:

```
@pdf.Image(filename , -width/2,  -height/2, width, height);
```

this should make working with rotation easier.

In case you also use scale and skew, would be better that you override the fabric toObject method to output the complete transformation of the object:

```
var objToObj = fabric.Object.prototype.toObject;

 fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = function(propToInclude) {
   var normalToObj = objToObj.call(this, propToInclude);
   normalToObj.transformation = this.calcTransformMatrix();
   return normalToObj;
 };
```

Then when is pdf time, see if you can apply a generic transform ( that transformation property ) and then draw the object ( any ) from -widht/2, -height/2 to width, height.